# FileMaker Pro 14 - Percent Summary of Summary

Tags: filemaker

So here's how the database is designed:

People
Entities
Hours

There are multiple people and multiple entities. I need to calculate each person's per entity total and the percentage of that total towards their total hours. So here's an example:

The database:

```
Name        Entity          5
Person1     Entity 1        5
Person1     Entity 2        10
Person1     Entity 1        10
Person1     Entity 2        2
Person2     Entity 1        12
Person2     Entity 1        8
Person2     Entity 1        5
Person2     Entity 2        15
```

Expected Result:

```
Name        Entity      Total Hours Percent  Percent Expected (against 40)
Person1     Entity 1        15      56%      37.5%
Person1     Entity 2        12      44%      30%
Person2     Entity 1        25      62.5%    62.5%
Person2     Entity 2        15      37.5%    37.5%
```

I can display the total hours for each entity per person, but I'm not sure how to grab the total of their hours while also calculating each entity's total hours against the total hours of each person while separately calculating the total of each entities hours (per person) against a static number.

It's not as complex as it sounds, and if this were Excel it would be a breeze, but doing it in FileMaker has proven a bit more challenging.

Comment: Where is the number 40 coming from?

Comment: Random static number of what you'd expect the entity total for each person to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place these fields in a sub-summary by Entity part (next to the Name and Entity fields):

[image]

This is assuming the "expected" value of 40 is supposed to be hard-coded (although you *could* take it from a global field or another calculation).

Comment: I didn't need the second summary, but the "GetSummary" part of the calculation was exactly what I needed.